# Clearing OnGoing Notifcations From My Application

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have multiple notifications from my application and the notifications are set to ongoing notification. I want to clear the notification when `addaction` performs on particular notification.

I can't know the notification id because these are set dynamically. can

Comment: Do you want to remove a notification when user selects one?

Comment: yupe! When user wants clicks on the particular one it must dismiss

Comment: I want to be this one